# How can I draw 3 straight arrows pointing to the same thing?

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, tikz-cd

In the following figure:

```
 \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow{r}{f} \arrow[swap]{dr}{g\circ f} & B \arrow{d}{g} \\
     & C
  \end{tikzcd}
```

I want to draw 3 straight arrows pointing from $B$ to the same thing which is $C$ with the maps written sometimes above and sometimes below the arrows.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.5cm, column sep=1.7cm]
A \arrow{r}{f} \arrow[swap]{dr}{g\circ f} & B \arrow[d, "g" description]\arrow[d, shift left=1.3ex] \arrow[d, shift right=1.3ex] \\
 & C
```

\end{tikzcd}

```
\end{document}
```

[image]